# Get SVG Element

Tags: anychart

In anychart I'm trying to get the SVG element linked to a bubble point.
There seems to be no build in methods for this.
Does anybody know if or how this can be done.

Some sample code to understand what direction I'm going:

```
var chart = anychart.fromJson(chartJson);
const count = chart.getSeriesCount();
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const series = chart.getSeriesAt(i);
    var count2 = series.data().getRowsCount();
    for (var j = 0; j < count2; j++) {
        const point = series.getPoint(j);
        //Get the SVGElement linked to the point.
    }
}
```